# jQuery load table from ajax and auto update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table

I've been searching for a solution to this problem on Google for a while, but
I'm either looking for the wrong thing, or I can't find something that
accomplishes my needs.

I need a jQuery table plugin or the respective functionality that can accomplish
the following:

- Load table contents via AJAX
- Automatic pagination
- Column sorting
- Auto-update timeout (every so often, talk to AJAX and update ONLY the rows that have changed or need to be added) **<-- This is the most important.**

I assume the implementation of it would be something similar to:

```
<table class="autoTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Custom Row Name 1</th>
            <th>Custom Row Name 2</th>
            <th>Custom Row Name 3</th>
            <th>Custom Row Name 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And something similar to:

```
$('.autoTable').each(function() {
    $(this).autoTable({
        timeout: 500
        url:     "ajax/test.json"
    });
});
```

That uses an JSON value like:

```
[
    {
        "row1": "Lorem",
        "row2": "Ipsum",
        "row3": "Dolor",
        "row4": "Sit"
    },
    {
        "row1": "Lorem",
        "row2": "Ipsum",
        "row3": "Dolor",
        "row4": "Sit"
    },
    {
        "row1": "Lorem",
        "row2": "Ipsum",
        "row3": "Dolor",
        "row4": "Sit"
    },
    {
        "row1": "Lorem",
        "row2": "Ipsum",
        "row3": "Dolor",
        "row4": "Sit"
    },
    {
        "row1": "Lorem",
        "row2": "Ipsum",
        "row3": "Dolor",
        "row4": "Sit"
    },
    {
        "row1": "Lorem",
        "row2": "Ipsum",
        "row3": "Dolor",
        "row4": "Sit"
    },
    {
        "row1": "Lorem",
        "row2": "Ipsum",
        "row3": "Dolor",
        "row4": "Sit"
    }

]
```

Hopefully you know of something.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at here, best data grid in jquery that i know: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: I'm not finding anything in the documentation about the last requirement, have you seen how to do this?

Comment: You should implement your own logic for an auto-update timeout. But for sure its possible using jqgrid. Ive already made something similar for a client.

Comment: @syntaqx Your last requirement is a tall order and you're just going to have to custom develop it. There's no way out of it.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* **[DataTables](http://datatables.net/)**, which can achieve your first three requirements, but I highly doubt there's a ready solution for your last requirement. While pretty sophisticated, I've (personally) found DataTables' documentation for custom development disorganized and difficult to understand.

Comment: I saw DataTables, but the last requirement is basically the most important :P. The disorganization and (in my time using it) chaotic structure it seems to have was a big turn off.